# How to convert boolean value to text and color using converter in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

I want to bind FontAwesome/MaterialFont icon and a color using the boolean value. I have successfully bind the Font icon but could not be able to bind the color.

isSQL is the boolean value

**Code...**

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool boolValue)
        {
            string trueFontIcon = "\U000f05e0"; 
            string falseFontIcon = "\U000f05d6";

            Color trueColor = Color.Green;
            Color falseColor = Color.Red;

            return boolValue ? (trueFontIcon,trueColor) : (falseFontIcon, falseColor);
        }
        return ("\U000f1522", Color.Gray); 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

**XAML...**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:BooleanToFontIconConverter x:Key="BooleanToFontIconConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>



<Label Grid.Column="1" tooltip:TooltipEffect.Text="{Binding sqlMessage}" FontFamily="MaterialFont">
    <Binding Path="isSQL" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToFontIconConverter}" />
</Label>
```

Comment: Where is the code for binding the color?  What specific problem are you having with it?

Comment: @Jason I have put the wrong class. I have updated the code. Icon is binding correctly but not the color.

Comment: `TextColor` is a separate property.  I don't think you can have a single converter handle both.  You could just use two Labels and toggle their visibility with a converter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to channge the Text and TextColor using one Converter, you could try   using a [ConverterParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#binding-converter-parameters).

When you use Bindings,

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" tooltip:TooltipEffect.Text="{Binding sqlMessage}" FontFamily="MaterialFont"
       Text="{Binding isSQL,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToFontIconConverter},ConverterParameter="Text"}"
       TextColor="{Binding isSQL,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToFontIconConverter},ConverterParameter="TextColor"}">
</Label>
```

So in **BooleanToFontIconConverter**, you may decide FontIcon or TextColor to return depending on **ConverterParameter** passed in,

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string param = parameter as string;
    
    if (value is bool boolValue)
    {
        string trueFontIcon = "\U000f05e0";
        string falseFontIcon = "\U000f05d6";

        Color trueColor = Color.Green;
        Color falseColor = Color.Red;

        if(param == "Text")
        {
            return boolValue ? trueFontIcon : falseFontIcon;
        }
        else
        {
            return boolValue ? trueColor : falseColor;
        }
    }
...
```

Now you could change the TextColor and FontIcon at the same time.

Hope it helps!

Please let me know if you have any question.